# Why does my code print "\"O.O…\" ! That’s an invalid input." at the end of every option except for option number 4

Tags: java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userName;
        Double randomNumber;
        /* Ask user for name */
        System.out.println("Hi, enter your name!  ");
        userName = console.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
        /* Ask user for number */
        System.out.println("There are four displays here: 1) DOG , 2) LOVE, 3) a random number\r\n"
                + "generated by Math.random(), and 4) Bye.\r\n"
                + "Please enter your choice by type in 1, 2, 3, or 4. ");
        int userNumber = console.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        if (userNumber==1)
        {
            /* prints output */
            System.out.println("\"" + userName + "\"! Thank you for choosing DOG."); // output
            System.out.println(" _   _\r\n" // output
                    + "/(. .)\\    )\r\n"
                    + "  (*)____/|\r\n"
                    + "  /       |\r\n"
                    + " /   |--\\ |\r\n"
                    + "(_)(_)  (_)");
        }
        
        if (userNumber==2) 
        {
            /* prints output */
            System.out.println("\"" + userName + "\"! Thank you for choosing LOVE."); // output
            System.out.println("        @@@@@@           @@@@@@\r\n" // output
                    + "      @@@@@@@@@@       @@@@@@@@@@\r\n"
                    + "    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r\n"
                    + "  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r\n"
                    + " @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r\n"
                    + "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r\n"
                    + "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r\n"
                    + "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r\n"
                    + " @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r\n"
                    + "  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r\n"
                    + "   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r\n"
                    + "    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r\n"
                    + "      @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r\n"
                    + "        @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r\n"
                    + "          @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r\n"
                    + "            @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r\n"
                    + "              @@@@@@@@@@@\r\n"
                    + "                @@@@@@@\r\n"
                    + "                  @@@\r\n"
                    + "                   @");
        }

        
        if (userNumber==3) 
        {
            /* prints output */
            System.out.println("\"" + userName + "\"! Thank you for choosing a Random Number."); // output
            randomNumber = Math.random();
            System.out.println("The Number you choose is " + randomNumber); // output
            System.out.println("");
        }
        
        if (userNumber==4) 
        {
            /* prints output */
            System.out.println("\"" + userName + "\"! Thank you for ending the program.\r\n" // output
                    + "\r\n"
                    + " //Bye\\\\");
        }
        
        else
        {
            /* prints output */
            System.out.println("\"O.O…\" ! That’s an invalid input."); // output
        }
    }

}
```

---

Why does my code print ""O.O…" ! That’s an invalid input." at the end of every option except for option number 4. How do I make ""O.O…" ! That’s an invalid input." only print if I type in a number other than 1, 2, 3, and 4? Thanks. ______________________________________________________________________________

Comment: Use `else if`, or use `switch` instead.

Comment: As Progman said you statement should be in the form of `if (...) {} else if (...) {} else {}` Currently the else block you added only belongs to your `if (userNumber==4)`  statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `else` is only associated with `if (userNumber == 4)`

For example, when `userNumber == 3`, then it isn't 4, so the else will be executed.

If you want a chain of conditions, you should use `if .. else if .. else if .. else`